# How to align content in right and left side of option select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select where I would like to display the contents of it separately.
On the left side, the option name, and on the right side this span.
How is it possible to make this separation?

```
 <select class="custom-select" id="groupSelect">
       <option value="1">Activity 1 <span>00:00:00</span> </option>
   </select>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8HAS.png)

Comment: Can't put html in an `<option>` so you would need to use a select replacement (dropdown) script that allows html. There are numerous such components easily found all over the web

Comment: It's very limited what you can do with those HTML items in terms of designing. That's why we create our custom lists and add functionality with JS.